# Is there any method for checking SFTP directory permission in Renci SSH.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I want to upload files to remote server via SSH.NET. Users login with their SSH credentials. And then I ask users where they're want to upload files. And then I need to check if there there are read/write permissions on this directory.

How can I check read/write permission on any directory?

I tried `SftpFile.OwnerCanWrite`/`OthersCanWrite`/`GroupCanWrite` but these are not working for current login user.

```cs
foreach (var directory in directories)
{
     if (!directory.Name.Equals(directoryName)) continue;

     // I want to check here if is there read/write permission.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to *"check"* for actual (aka effective) permissions for a specific operation with SFTP protocol. SFTP API does not provide such functionality nor enough information for you to decide on your own.
See also [How to check for read permission using JSch with SFTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16686858/850848)

The only way is to actually try to create the file. E.g. using `SftpClient.Create` method. *And after all, that's what you want to do, isn't it?*

---

Alternative solution is to [execute a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30883237/850848#44797940) like `test -w path` to check for the permissions, instead SFTP.